# Move from Internal to External

Tags: internal-sd

I am using an Motorola XT1022. I have moved the games and apps from the internal to SD card to free the internal memory, but still there are some moved apps files that are occupying the internal memory. So I can't install any other apps.

Can you tell me how to move that apps files to the SD card?

Answer (score 2):

If they are the default apps that came along with device you can not move them to card nor uninstall them. **Rooting** is the only method to do so. Be careful rooting **VOIDS warranty** of the mobile. Use *Clean Master* app from Play Store to clear junk files in internal memory.

Comment: It's worth noting that 'moving to SD' only moves a portion of the app to the SD, and Google no longer support external SD cards so I'd expect this to worsen as time goes by.

Comment: Yeah my Xperia won't support moving apps to card and there is no hope of getting that feature in future as per Sony Mobile Blog. Probably they are going to increase internal memory and end support to external cards like iPhone. Really iPhone is changing the things.